# The SQL Statement creates many connections and hangs DB

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT Distinct org.id_name,org.id_region,org.id_inn,org.id_kpp,org.id_username, agreements.id_agr_code,
agreements.id_crat, agreements.id_project_name, agreements.comment, agreements.comment2, agreements.id_factor, agreements.id_name,
month1.id_date_money,month1.id_done,month2.id_date_money,month2.id_done,month3.id_date_money,month3.id_done,month4.id_date_money,
month4.id_done,month5.id_date_money,month5.id_done,month6.id_date_money,month6.id_done FROM agreements
inner join org on (org.id_org=agreements.id_org)
LEFT OUTER JOIN money as month1 ON (agreements.id_agr = month1.id_dogovor) and ( month1.id_date_money is NULL OR month1.id_date_money=:Month1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN money as month2 ON (agreements.id_agr = month2.id_dogovor) and ( month2.id_date_money is NULL OR month2.id_date_money=:Month2)
LEFT OUTER JOIN money as month3 ON (agreements.id_agr = month3.id_dogovor) and ( month3.id_date_money is NULL OR month3.id_date_money=:Month3)
LEFT OUTER JOIN money as month4 ON (agreements.id_agr = month4.id_dogovor) and ( month4.id_date_money is NULL OR month4.id_date_money=:Month4)
LEFT OUTER JOIN money as month5 ON (agreements.id_agr = month5.id_dogovor) and ( month5.id_date_money is NULL OR month5.id_date_money=:Month5)
LEFT OUTER JOIN money as month6 ON (agreements.id_agr = month6.id_dogovor) and ( month6.id_date_money is NULL OR month6.id_date_money=:Month6)
where agreements.id_old=:Archive
and case when :region is null then org.id_region=org.id_region else FIND_IN_SET(org.id_region, :region) end
and case when :users is null then org.id_user=org.id_user else FIND_IN_SET(org.id_user, :users) end
and case when :agrtype is null then agreements.id_type=agreements.id_type else FIND_IN_SET(agreements.id_type, :agrtype) end
and case when :agrproject is null then agreements.id_project_name=agreements.id_project_name else FIND_IN_SET(agreements.id_project_name, :agrproject) end
ORDER BY org.id_name
```

This SQL statement in MySQL takes up very many minutes to complete and at some point hangs the BD because it creates a lot of connections which are root and say "copying to tmp_table". The error message says "Too many connections to BD".

I think this is because of FIND_IN_SET but I am unsure. I can't a find a different way to rewrite this SQL so that it executes faster and doesn't create all those connections (it keeps on creating them until it fills it up to max).

The idea is to show which Agreements of which Organization has payment in the defined months and which doesn't. The filter of regions is in numbers 01,05,09,23,26,91 and e.t.c and the filter of users is in user_id integers. The filter of agrtypes is in strings and agrprojects is in strings too. The ID_old is a boolean flag. ID_agr, ID_Dogovor, and id_org are primary keys Integer.

Comment: As you haven't normalized your database, but decided to have comma-separated lists in columns instead, you have also decided against speed. In order to know which record contains a certain region for instance all records must be read and checked, whereas with an org_region table, the DBMS would probably use an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `agreements.id_old` an ID or just some flag indicating that the ID is in an old format or the like? If it's really an ID, it probably won't occur often in the table. Maybe even just once? Then an index on the column should make the access pretty fast. You should also have an index on `money.id_dogovor`.

I suggest the following indexes:

```
create index idx1 on agreements(id_old, id_org, id_agr);
create index idx2 on money(id_dogovor, id_date_money, id_done);
```

(I surmise that a unique index on `org(id_org)` exists, as this seems to be the table's primary key.)

Comment: The id_old is a boolean flag.

Comment: Why does the Query create a lot of connections that say "copying to tmp_table"? because of this the query fails and nobody can connect to the db until they are terminated automatically.